# Variable width form for a variable width div?

Tags: css, forms, html

Is there a way (CSS) for me to make sure that a textbox and search button vary sizes when the div does?

This is what my search bar looks like:

```
<div class="userinfo">
    <form><table id="search" border="0"><tr>
            <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="search"></td>
            <td valign="top"><input type="image" name="search-button" src="img/search.png"></td>
    </tr></table></form>
</div>
```

And `userinfo`:

```
.userinfo {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.userinfo input[type=text] { 
    width: 70% 
}
```

`userinfo` lies in the middle of the page with a width of `60%`, however, I am trying to get  the textbox within `userinfo` to be of a certain width relative to `userinfo`. The above isn't working. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should assign a percentage width to the search input as well.

It's also probably a good idea to keep the search button at a fixed width (although not necessary).

Edit: Here is an example:

```
<div class="widget">
    <input type="text" name="query">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</div>

<style>
    .widget { width: 30% }
    .widget input[type=text] { width: 70% }
</style>
```

Comment: What do I make the `.class` for? The form or input element?

Comment: I've edited my response to include an example. Note that this uses a CSS attribute selector that IE6 doesn't support (if you care).

Comment: I've edited my question to add some code snippets. I seem to be missing something

Comment: The table is the issue. Is it necessary?

Comment: It seems to be the only thing which keeps my textbox and "image" button aligned vertically.

Comment: You're right about the table. You've solved my problem so +1 and accept. Thanks :)

Comment: Add `.widget input[type=image] { vertical-align: middle }` and see if that helps. If not, adjust the value (try top, then bottom)